# Delete Document in DocumentDB if I do not know the Id?

Tags: json, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have a document db collection. Now, I got a json string, which is one of the document in the DocumentDB. How can I delete this document?

I know we can delete it using document's id. Does it mean I need to get the id from the document's json string?

The issue I have is: I do not know the type of the object, it could be different classes. In this case, what we could do?

I'm thinking we could parse the id using regular expression, but, it should be a better way to do this.

Thanks

Comment: Not sure what you mean, by not knowing the class. JSON documents don't need to map to classes. Why can't you simply search for the document to delete, based on the id (or something else) in the json doc? Also: Not sure why you think you need to use a regular expression to parse JSON, vs just using an appropriate JSON library for your given programming language. Please edit your question to clarify.

Comment: +1 to everything David said. Also, for questions like this it is often helpful to post what code you have even if you know it's not close. That tells us the gaps we can then help fill with answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use JObject.Parse() and then retrieve the id property.

http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm